# how to find out open file description for linux process?

Tags: linux, shell, centos, lsof

While runing my go program, i find out so many error such as "too many open files" in the logs, and i just to find out which process run out of the fds, and i run this command:

`lsof -n |awk '{print $2}'|sort|uniq -c |sort -nr`

it returns the result such as

`279605 20341
  62748 19861
  10310 19712
   5434 21318
   3484 27344
   2842 19781
   2400 20372
   2346 24153
   2123 5214
   1540 21123`

process which pid is **20341** is a **mongod** process, and i'm surprised about that. So i try another way：

`lsof -p 20341 | wc -l`

but something make me trouble is that it's result is：**567**.

After that， i try another way：`ll /proc/20341/fd | wc -l` which result is **496**。

And i am so confusion now，which one is right，and what the different between them？

thanks.

---

updated at：2018-05-31 10:35:33

- Get the mongodb PID

  `[root@node26 10:34:54 ~]$ps aux | grep mongo
  mongodb  20341  2.4  1.9 25419812 1257420 ?    Sl   May28 107:58 /usr/bin/mongod --quiet -f /etc/mongod.conf run`
- Command `lsof -p`

  `[root@node26 10:36:12 ~]$lsof -p 20341 | wc -l
  570`
- Directory

  `[root@node26 10:36:33 ~]$ll /proc/20341/fd/ | wc -l
  499`
- Command `lsof + grep`

  `[root@node26 10:37:33 ~]$lsof | grep 20341 | wc -l
  282223`

  - front 10

    `mongod    20341              mongodb  cwd       DIR              9,127       4096          2 /
    mongod    20341              mongodb  rtd       DIR              9,127       4096          2 /
    mongod    20341              mongodb  txt       REG              9,127   12238320    2499177 /usr/bin/mongod
    mongod    20341              mongodb  mem       REG              9,127   67108864    1969114 /var/lib/mongodb/a_dev.0
    mongod    20341              mongodb  mem       REG              9,127  536870912    1968852 /var/lib/mongodb/a_dev.ns
    mongod    20341              mongodb  mem       REG              9,127   67108864    1968447 /var/lib/mongodb/a.0
    mongod    20341              mongodb  mem       REG              9,127  536870912    1968347 /var/lib/mongodb/a.ns
    mongod    20341              mongodb  mem       REG              9,127   67108864    1968453 /var/lib/mongodb/b.0
    mongod    20341              mongodb  mem       REG              9,127  536870912    1968449 /var/lib/mongodb/b.ns
    mongod    20341              mongodb  mem       REG              9,127   67108864    1968590 /var/lib/mongodb/c.0`
  - middle 10

    `mongod    20341 27018        mongodb  490u     IPv4          143223380        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node24:59172 (ESTABLISHED)
    mongod    20341 27018        mongodb  491u     IPv4          143758325        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node25:43016 (ESTABLISHED)
    mongod    20341 27018        mongodb  492u     IPv4          143762443        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node24:60602 (ESTABLISHED)
    mongod    20341 27018        mongodb  493u     IPv4          154865226        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node26:54800 (ESTABLISHED)
    mongod    20341 27018        mongodb  494u     IPv4          164046515        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node24:42952 (ESTABLISHED)
    mongod    20341 27018        mongodb  495u     IPv4          164046516        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node24:42960 (ESTABLISHED)
    mongod    20341 27018        mongodb  497u     IPv4          154865844        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node25:41976 (ESTABLISHED)
    mongod    20341 27018        mongodb  500u     IPv4          164046517        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node24:42968 (ESTABLISHED)
    mongod    20341 27018        mongodb  502u     IPv4          164046518        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node26:60306 (ESTABLISHED)
    mongod    20341 27018        mongodb  503u     IPv4          164046519        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node26:60314 (ESTABLISHED)`
  - tail 10

    `mongod    20341 32608        mongodb  492u     IPv4          143762443        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node24:60602 (ESTABLISHED)
    mongod    20341 32608        mongodb  493u     IPv4          154865226        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node26:54800 (ESTABLISHED)
    mongod    20341 32608        mongodb  494u     IPv4          164046515        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node24:42952 (ESTABLISHED)
    mongod    20341 32608        mongodb  495u     IPv4          164046516        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node24:42960 (ESTABLISHED)
    mongod    20341 32608        mongodb  497u     IPv4          154865844        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node25:41976 (ESTABLISHED)
    mongod    20341 32608        mongodb  500u     IPv4          164046517        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node24:42968 (ESTABLISHED)
    mongod    20341 32608        mongodb  502u     IPv4          164046518        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node26:60306 (ESTABLISHED)
    mongod    20341 32608        mongodb  503u     IPv4          164046519        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node26:60314 (ESTABLISHED)
    mongod    20341 32608        mongodb  505u     IPv4          164046523        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node26:60322 (ESTABLISHED)
    mongod    20341 32608        mongodb  730u     IPv4          117137926        0t0        TCP node26:27017->node25:54730 (ESTABLISHED)`

Answer (score 1):

`/proc/${pid}/fd` contains file descriptors connected to the shell, which show up as a number followed by a `u` in `lsof`:

```
$ la /proc/$$/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 username users 64 May 30 20:08 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 username users 64 May 30 20:08 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 username users 64 May 30 20:08 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 username users 64 May 30 20:08 255 -> /dev/pts/0
$ lsof -p $$
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
bash    3720 username  cwd    DIR  254,3    12288 1835009 /home/username
bash    3720 username  rtd    DIR  254,2     4096       2 /
bash    3720 username  txt    REG  254,2   859688 2890163 /usr/bin/bash
bash    3720 username  mem    REG  254,2    46912 2885785 /usr/lib/libnss_files-2.27.so
bash    3720 username  mem    REG  254,2  2942480 2930144 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
bash    3720 username  mem    REG  254,2   457800 2890072 /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.1
bash    3720 username  mem    REG  254,2  2105608 2885835 /usr/lib/libc-2.27.so
bash    3720 username  mem    REG  254,2    14144 2885777 /usr/lib/libdl-2.27.so
bash    3720 username  mem    REG  254,2   363064 2890132 /usr/lib/libreadline.so.7.0
bash    3720 username  mem    REG  254,2   177680 2885836 /usr/lib/ld-2.27.so
bash    3720 username    0u   CHR  136,0      0t0       3 /dev/pts/0
bash    3720 username    1u   CHR  136,0      0t0       3 /dev/pts/0
bash    3720 username    2u   CHR  136,0      0t0       3 /dev/pts/0
bash    3720 username  255u   CHR  136,0      0t0       3 /dev/pts/0
```

They are both "right," but the count from `lsof` is the one relevant for running out of open files.

To find the relevant open files limit use `ulimit -n`.

Comment: okay。。。and why `lsof | grep <pid>` different with `lsof -p <pid>` ?

Comment: Because `lsof | grep $pid` looks for a string *anywhere* in a massive output which probably happens to contain that number in a bunch of other places.

Comment: I don't think it's the reason, because i get the result of lsof | grep <pid> and watch the result, they are really relative with the <pid>, not other process's opened fd.

Comment: Without seeing the output there's no way I can judge what the issue is. Could you paste the diff in your question?

Comment: thks l0b0, i just append the result of my environment.